# How to disable the Slack minipanel?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, slack

I am using the Slack app on my ArchLinux laptop running KDE Plasma 5.12.4.
Whenever I'm in a call and switch application, desktop or activity the Slack minipanel appears.

Since it appears as a new window it triggers a notification in the Icons-only Task Manager widget which makes the auto-hiding panel appear even though I don't really care about it.

---

**Long story short I don't want the Slack minipanel to appear.**
I have found no option to disable it from within the app.

How can I disable this minipanel?

Comment: Have you looked into the option of blacklisting the notification instead?

Comment: @Carolus I switched to i3 in the meantime, though feel free to post this as an answer (with steps and reference links if needed) if you believe it could solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the mini-panel from activating the taskbar, we can add a Window Rule to KDE like this:

[image: prevent slack mini panel from triggering the taskbar]

The important parts:

- *Window class:* unimportant
- *Window types:* Normal window
- *Window title:* Exact match, `Slack | mini panel`
- *Skip taskbar:* Force, yes

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like your sidebar to take up less space in your Slack window, you can adjust the width or collapse it completely: Click and drag the edge of your sidebar to adjust it to your preferred width. Press ⌘ShiftD (Mac) or CtrlShiftD (Windows/Linux) to collapse or open the sidebar whenever you’d like.